# MacBook Pro 2017 doesn't connect Dell U2713HM via (Hama) USB-C to DisplayPort adapter but MacBook 2016 works

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, displayport

I am trying to connect MacBook Pro 2017 to Dell U2712HM monitor. I bought Hama USB-C to Display Port adapter but it does not work with MBP 2017. When I plugged it, it does not recognize it - nothing happens. Strange enough, the same adapter works just fine with MacBook 2016. I read that Apple has changed USB-C in some way for 2017 version.

So, if this is true, is there USB-C to DisplayPort cable (adapter) that actually works with 2017 MacBooks?  Or is there some USB-C to USB-C adapter that provide functionality of 2016 USB-C? Actually, Hyper support told me that I should buy their hub (https://www.hypershop.com/collections/usb-type-c/products/hyperdrive-hub-for-usb-c-macbook-pro-13-and-15-2016-2017) and use hub's primary USB-C port to connect USB-C to DP cable.

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't work; though I can't vouch for a solution that'll work for you, these [USB-C to Mini DisplayPort cables](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B073S6V9CD/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1) worked for connecting two 2009 27" iMacs to a 2017 15" MacBook Pro using Target Display Mode.

Comment: Same here, but with 2018 mbpro, 2016 worked just fine.